# Callback when choosing date range with the easepick plugin

Tags: javascript, datepicker

I am using the [easepick](https://easepick.com) plugin to provide my users with a method to choose a date range. But I am struggling to get an event to fire when the data range is chosen. Anyone who can help with solving this problem?

```js
enableEasepick = function() {
  const picker = new easepick.create({
    element: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
    grid: 2,
    zIndex: "1000",
    calendars: 2,
    css: [
      'https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@easepick/bundle@1.2.1/dist/index.css'
    ],
    plugins: ['RangePlugin', 'LockPlugin'],
    RangePlugin: {
      tooltipNumber(num) {
        return num - 1;
      },
      locale: {
        one: 'night',
        other: 'nights',
      },
    },
    LockPlugin: {
      minDate: new Date(),
      minDays: 2,
      inseparable: true,
    },

    autoApply: true,
  });
};
```

The following does not work:

```js
var input = document.getElementById('datepicker');
input.addEventListener("change", function() {
});
```

Comment: Event handlers like change will only fire if the field value was changed directly by the user - not if any script sets the value. You need to use the custom events provided by this library - https://easepick.com/packages/core.html#events

Comment: Arh you are right. Overlooked that one. Thanks. If you add it to answers I'll accept and close.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Standard event handlers like `change` will only fire if the field value was changed directly by the user - not if any script sets the value.

You need to use the custom events provided by this library - https://easepick.com/packages/core.html#events

> `select` - Event is called when selection is submitted.

That's probably the one you want here.

Answer (score 0):

On the second line
"const picker = new easepick.create({"
You forgot to add the second ).
I believe part of the code isn't connecting properly. "const picker = neweasepick.create() {" would help the code connect and help the event work.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).